# Bad request in Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

When I request something to python by AJAX, everything runs OK in python, but, when the route return my informations for AJAX, simply he create another blank page with the text that I returned, and not did what I want in the page who needs to be. 
Here the response image
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwFan.png)
Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bot():
    texto = request.form['text']
    print(texto)
    conversation = ConversationV1(
      username='a33eb2c9-d218-4e05-a8ff-a46b59c5c3b1',
      password='VATP3XEHsrPL',
      version='2017-05-26'
    )

    context = {}

    workspace_id = '96cbce3b-2fd3-49b0-ad57-da62c33547ee'   

    user = texto
    response = conversation.message(
      workspace_id=workspace_id,
      message_input={'text': user},
      context=context
    )
    context = response['context']

    #se há intenções e dialogo
    if response['intents'] or response['entities']:

        if response['intents']:
            intent = (json.dumps(response['intents'][0]['intent'],indent = 2))
            intent = intent[1:-1]

        dialog = (json.dumps(response['output']['nodes_visited'][0],indent = 2))
        dialog = dialog[1:-1]

        #se há resesposta à intenção
        if response['output']['text']:
            resposta = json.dumps(response['output']['text'][0],sort_keys=True, indent=4)
            resposta = resposta[1:-1]
            resposta = resposta.encode('utf-8')
            resp = (resposta.decode('unicode-escape'))

        #se entrou no nó x,y,z
        if dialog == "perfil_e_id":
            ID = (json.dumps(response['entities'][0]['value'],indent = 2))
            ID = ID[1:-1]
            print (ID)
            resp = perfill(ID)

        elif dialog == "perfil":
            return resp
            ID = texto
            print ("Ikrl : " + ID)
            resp = perfil()

        elif dialog == "heroi":
            ID = (json.dumps(response['entities'][0]['value']))
            ID = ID[1:-1]
            resp = herostats(int(ID))
            return resp

        elif dialog == "counterheroi":
            ID = (json.dumps(response['entities'][0]['value']))
            ID = ID[1:-1]
            resp = herostats(int(ID))
            return resp

    else:
        resposta = json.dumps(response['output']['text'][0],sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        resposta = resposta[1:-1]
        resposta = resposta.encode('utf-8')
        resp = (resposta.decode('unicode-escape'))

    print (resp)
    return resp
```

And my ajax code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".mytext").on("keyup", function(e){
        if (e.which == 13){
            var text = $(this).val();
            if (text !== ""){
                insertChat("me", text);
                document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = text;              
                $(this).val('');
            }
            $.ajax({
              url: '/',
              data: $(text),
              type: 'POST',

              success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                insertChat("you", response)

              },
              error: function(error){
                console.log(error)
              }
            })
        }
    });
  });
```

if you need test in your pc, I upload a .rar file 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9TVHd_5neJ1amdqZWVrbm9mX2c

Answer (score 0):

You haven't cancelled the default submit action.

```
if (e.which == 13){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: Not working, Fun is I have a similar application and the code is almost exactly and work fine